# decision tree for significant variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, classification, decision-tree

how can I use decision tree graph to determine the significant variables,I know which one has largest information gain should be in the root of tree which means  has small entropy so this is my graph if I want to know which variables are significant how can I interpret

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What does significant mean to you? At each node, the variable selected it the most significant given the context and assuming that selecting by information gain will actually work (it's not always the case). For example, at node 11, BB is the most significant discriminator given AA>20.

Clearly, AA and BB are the most useful assuming selecting by information gain gives the best way to partition the data. The rest give further refinement. C and N would be next.

What you should be asking is: Should I keep all the nodes?

The answer depends on many things and there is likely no best answer.
One way would be by using the total case count of each leaf and merge them.

Not sure how I would do this given your image. It's not really clear what is being shown at the leaves and what 'n' is. Also not sure what 'p' is.

Comment: AA,N,BB these are attributes (variables ) based on this tree I want to say these attributes are significant

Comment: I got that. What's needed is a short description of each element in the image and what is being shown. E.g., p<0.001 means what exactly? 'p' is entropy?, probability? other?. The leaves are showing what? What is n? Number of cases? if the side axis of each leaf is class then how does one get a distribution of classes in a single case (if n==1 means that in node 17).?

Comment: all of them in this tree are variables non of them are class sorry but I understand p is probability am I right ? because in the formula of Information gain we have E which is entropy and we have p which probability

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Generally, one uses this to discriminate classes. Entropy is the number of bits (or other units) of information learned by receiving a particular value of variable. It's obtained from a calculation using probability. Generally you key off of Info Gain or Mutual Info. I suspect you are using a package and don't understand how it works; what it is intended to do; or what it is telling you.

Comment: today I studied decision tree and  I know calculate by formula and creating tree but I don't know using tree to decide which attributes  are significant

Comment: OK. I still think you created the image using something you didn't make. You don't seem to understand what's being depicted. See my answer above. Clearly, AA and BB are the most important followed by C and N. Each of the other values gives a refinement. Only you can say how much refinement is needed.

Comment: hhh believe me I created by my self I have code if you want  I will give you and today studied and I know which one has less entropy will get high information gain this is the link that I read bout tree                                                     http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/teaching/pre2012/v231/lecture11.html

Comment: Well, this isn't the place for a general discussion. Have I answered your question or not? If not, what am I not saying?

Comment: sorry ...the problem is not clear for me your answer as I said today I studied decision tree so if you can explain based on this graph I will really appreciated thanks

Comment: Then  state what you don't understand or edit your question to be more explicit about what you expect. I hope you aren't searching for the answer to a homework problem that you can cut and paste to turn in. AA is first because it's the root. BB is the only variable used on the second level. What else do you want?

Comment: ok thanks I am still reading about decision tree to get more knowledge about it